# What is wrong with my assembly code that is trying to swap each element of an even array with the element that is next to it?

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, masm, swap

I am taking a beginner assembly code class and I can't figure out what is going wrong. I moved `arr+1` (the second element in the array `arr`) into EDX at the end just to check if the correct value is there and unfortunately it is not. It says 01000000 in EDX not 00000001 like it should. However, when I was going through the code, 1 and 2 then 3 and 4 were all correctly moved into EAX and EBX. So that means there is some problem with my code. From looking at other solutions online, I know that there are other ways of solving this problem that have already been posted on this site, but at the moment this is what I am learning in class so this method of getting the reference and moving it into registers is going to be the best option for me to actually understand what is going on.

This is all of the code:

```
.386
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess proto,dwExitCode:dword

.data
arr dword 1, 2, 3, 4

.code
main proc

    mov esi, offset arr
    mov ecx, lengthof arr
L1:
    mov eax, [esi]
    mov ebx, [esi + 4]
    mov [esi], ebx
    mov [esi + 4], eax
    add esi, type arr
    Loop L1

    mov edx, arr + 1

    invoke ExitProcess,0
main endp
end main
```

Comment: `add esi, type arr` only advances by one element, so doing that while swapping pairs moves one element along like in bubble-sort.  Also, `mov edx, arr + 1` after the loop does an unaligned load from 1 byte after the start of the first element.  Use a debugger to easily look at memory after your loop finishes (and while it's running)

Comment: Thank you! What do you mean by an unaligned load? I have been using the debugger, but I can't tell what is happening in the array from it past the first element.

Comment: Also, I can see what you are saying with add esi, type arr only incrementing it by one. However, when I tried to switch it to 'add esi, type arr * 2' there was a problem. What is the way I would fix that?

Comment: Using Visual Studio? In a memory window (Debug > Windows > Memory > open any of them) you can type `&arr` in the address box to view the memory. In the Watch window, you can add `&arr,4` as a watch (4 is the length that you want the array to be).

Comment: Thank you, this was incredibly helpful to me

Answer (score 1):

This is how your array looks in memory:

```
arr
|
v
1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, ?, ?, ?, ?
```

> I moved `arr+1` (the second element in the array `arr`) into EDX

Your array uses dword-sized elements. Therefore, the address of the second element is `arr + 4` (since a dword is 4 bytes).

> to check if the correct value is there and unfortunately it is not. It says 01000000 in EDX not 00000001 like it should.

When I run your present code (that also reads and writes memory that does not belong to the array) I don't get those results at all!

```
arr
|
v
2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, ?, ?, ?, ?, 1, 0, 0, 0
   ^
   |
   arr+1
```

Executing `mov edx, arr+1` produces neither 01000000h nor 00000001h. It will produce 03000000h.

> Also, I can see what you are saying with `add esi, type arr` only incrementing it by one. However, when I tried to switch it to `add esi, type arr * 2` there was a problem. What is the way I would fix that?

The task asks you to swap pairs of array elements. With each swap, you will have 'consumed' **2** elements, so you need to walk through the array in steps of 2 elements or 8 bytes (which you can write as `(type arr) * 2`).
What you still need to consider is *how many times you can swap elements*! Your particular array has 4 elements. Therefore, you can only do 2 pairwise swaps at most. You can request this writing `mov ecx, (lengthof arr) / 2`.

---

*The following is a nitpick, but only if you consider it a nitpick!*

In your program, I don't see much benefit from having `add esi, type arr` instead of the simpler `add esi, 4` (before corrections). It does not look good together with those hard-coded displacements `[esi + 4]`

The real value from using `type arr` would be to obtain a program that can deal with another size array requiring only a minimal change to the `.data` section (`arr dword 1, 2, 3, 4` or `arr word 1, 2, 3, 4` or `arr byte 1, 2, 3, 4`):

```
    mov    esi, offset arr
    mov    ecx, lengthof arr
L1:
  IF (type arr) = 4
    mov    eax, [esi]
    mov    ebx, [esi + 4]
    mov    [esi], ebx
    mov    [esi + 4], eax
    add    esi, 8
  ELSEIF (type arr) = 2
    movzx  eax, word ptr [esi]
    movzx  ebx, word ptr [esi + 2]
    mov    [esi], bx
    mov    [esi + 2], ax
    add    esi, 4
  ELSEIF (type arr) = 1
    movzx  eax, byte ptr [esi]
    movzx  ebx, byte ptr [esi + 1]
    mov    [esi], bl
    mov    [esi + 1], al
    add    esi, 2
  ENDIF
    dec    ecx                    ; (*)
    jnz    L1
```

Alternatively:

```
    mov    esi, offset arr
    mov    ecx, lengthof arr
L1:
  IF (type arr) = 4
    mov    eax, [esi]
    mov    ebx, [esi + 4]
    mov    [esi], ebx
    mov    [esi + 4], eax
  ELSEIF (type arr) = 2
    movzx  eax, word ptr [esi]
    movzx  ebx, word ptr [esi + 2]
    mov    [esi], bx
    mov    [esi + 2], ax
  ELSEIF (type arr) = 1
    movzx  eax, byte ptr [esi]
    movzx  ebx, byte ptr [esi + 1]
    mov    [esi], bl
    mov    [esi + 1], al
  ENDIF
    add    esi, (type arr) * 2
    dec    ecx                    ; (*)
    jnz    L1
```

(*) Don't use `loop` in your 32-bit code. See [Why is the loop instruction slow? Couldn't Intel have implemented it efficiently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35742570/why-is-the-loop-instruction-slow-couldnt-intel-have-implemented-it-efficiently)